# Gradle remote cache node is not populating an EFS volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, gradle, terraform, amazon-ecs, amazon-efs

I am building the remote gradle cache node app in an ECS-EC2 task and it works as expected. Then we want that all the cache files generated go to an EFS Volume cache, with terraform the EFS volume seems to be corrected mounted on the EC2 machine, the issue is that the cache files from the task container are not going to the EFS Volume.

This is the dockerfile for the remote gradle cache:

```
FROM alpine:3.10
ENV GRADLE_USER=gradle \
  GRADLE_HOME=/home/gradle \
  LANG=C.UTF-8 

# Installing OpenJDK 11
RUN apk update && \
  apk add --no-cache --purge --update bash curl wget && \
  apk add --no-cache --purge --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/community openjdk11 && \
  adduser -s /bin/bash -h ${GRADLE_HOME} -D ${GRADLE_USER}

USER ${GRADLE_USER}

# Installing Gradle Cache Node 9
RUN wget https://docs.gradle.com/build-cache-node/jar/build-cache-node-9.0.jar -O ${GRADLE_HOME}/build-cache-node-9.0.jar && \
  mkdir -p ${GRADLE_HOME}/data
COPY config.yaml ${GRADLE_HOME}/data/conf/config.yaml

EXPOSE 5071

WORKDIR ${GRADLE_HOME}

ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java -jar ${GRADLE_HOME}/build-cache-node-9.0.jar --data-dir ${GRADLE_HOME}/data --port 5071"]
```

This the ECS task on terraform:

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "gradle_cache_task_definition" {
  family                    = local.tags.name
  requires_compatibilities  = ["EC2"]
  execution_role_arn        = module.ecs_execution_iam_role.role_arn
  task_role_arn             = module.ecs_task_iam_role.role_arn  
  cpu                       = var.ecs_container_cpu
  memory                    = var.ecs_container_memory
  container_definitions     = templatefile("templates/${local.tags.name}/ecs-task-definition.json.tpl",
    {
      full_product_name   = local.tags.name
      product_name        = var.product_name
      cpu                 = var.ecs_task_cpu
      memory              = var.ecs_task_memory
      image               = aws_ecr_repository.gradle_cache_ecr.repository_url
      version             = var.ecs_image_version
      volume_name         = "${var.product_name}-${var.environment}"
      container_port      = var.ecs_task_container_port
      host_port           = var.ecs_task_host_port
      container_path      = var.ecs_task_container_path
      region              = var.aws_region
    }
  )
 
  volume {
    name = "${var.product_name}-${var.environment}"
    
    efs_volume_configuration {
     file_system_id = aws_efs_file_system.gradle_cache_efs.id
     root_directory = "/"  
     }
           
      
  }

  tags = local.resolved_tags
  
}
```

And this is the task definition:

```
[
  {
    "name": "${full_product_name}",
    "cpu": ${cpu},
    "memory": ${memory},
    "image": "${image}:${version}",
    "portMappings": [  
      {
        "containerPort": ${container_port},
        "hostPort": ${host_port},
        "protocol": "tcp"
      }
    ],
    "mountPoints": [
      {
        "sourceVolume": "${volume_name}",
        "containerPath": "${container_path}",
        "readOnly": false
      }
    ],
    "logConfiguration": {
      "logDriver": "awslogs",
      "options": {
        "awslogs-group": "${full_product_name}",
        "awslogs-region": "${region}",
        "awslogs-stream-prefix": "${product_name}"
      }
    },
    "volumesFrom": [],
    "environment": [],
    "essential": true
  }
]
```

The container_path variable in tfvars is setted like this:

```
ecs_task_container_path = "/opt/gradle/data/system/cache"
```

The issue is as you can see, the cache data on the container is created on /home/gradle/data/system/cache, but the container_path only works in /opt/gradle/data/system/cache, if I change that path the task on ecs in stopped. The EFS volume is never populated so I am think that is the reason but dont know yet how to resolve it.

Any sugestion or recomendation would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this is your problem: `"${/opt/gradle/data/system/cache}",` You're trying to resolve a variable/parameter named "/opt/gradle/data/system/cache", which is probably resolving as an empty string. Just get rid of the `${}` there. To verify, check what the current ECS task definition looks like in the AWS console, I bet the container path is blank. Or looking again, maybe that should be `${container_path}`?

Comment: Hi, yes, my bad, I put it there to show how is seetted the variable, the code is like this:
"mountPoints": [
      {
        "sourceVolume": "${volume_name}",
        "containerPath": "${container_path}",
        "readOnly": false
      }
and the variable is setted in terraform is:  ecs_task_container_path = "/opt/gradle/data/system/cache"